# it is correct delete data using method get?

Tags: node.js, http

I developer an application in nodejs using methods for delete one data, what method is correct for delete data GET or POST?

i using [EJS](https://ejs.co/) for render my template engine at framework express.

i am using

```
router.get('/delete-category/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    //delete
})
```

in this case i used method get, but what better method in this case, GET or POST.

```
router.post('/delete-category/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id
    if (id != undefined && id != null) {
      //delete  
}
```

Of course! the .ejs in this case i used one form and Method="POST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifying a "delete" operation in a browser form, it should be a POST.  From within a browser, think of GET as retrieving data and POST as modifying or deleting data.

If you're specifying a delete option in an API, you should use the actual DELETE verb in HTTP, but you can't use that in a browser form, so you can use a POST from a form.